# Mail to different email based on the current user role

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to send mail to different users based on the user role of who is logged in on my site. I cannot seem to figure out a proper way to do it. I am using letter_opener gem to test on a dev environment, it seems this logic is not working. Can anyone please help me figure out how to make this logic work?

```
class ContactFormsMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: ENV["DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL"]

  def send_mail(contact_form)
    @name    = contact_form.name
    @email   = contact_form.email
    @phone   = contact_form.phone
    @message = contact_form.body
    @postcode = contact_form.postcode

    if User.find_by_role('key_account')
      mail(to: ENV["CONTACT_FORM_KAM"], subject: build_subject(contact_form))
    else
      mail(to: ENV["CONTACT_FORM_EMAIL"], subject: build_subject(contact_form))
    end
  end

  def build_subject(contact_form)
    if contact_form.body.include?("Calibration Certificate request:")
      title = "CERTIFICATE REQUEST"
    else
      title = "#{ENV['COUNTRY_CODE']}: CONTACT FORM"
    end

    "#{title} - #{contact_form.email}"
  end
end
```

Comment: What does `User.find_by_role('key_account')` have to do with the currently logged in user?

Comment: Was trying to use that to check if the user has a key account role.

Comment: I see you saw your mistake :)  I'm going to vote to close this because it's not a helpful Q/A for others.

Answer (score 0):

All sorted. I just passed in the current user to the controller and used that on my mailer to check the currently logged-in user.